# Eclipse Neon 2.0 Append automatically comments

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Smalle question.
Is there a way to append automatically generate comments/trigger notification/popup window at the end of new code.
Example:

```
int i = 0; //my comment
```

Whenever I start writing "int i = 0;", "//my comment" is appended automatically.
Or if u have any suggestion regarding something like this.

Kind regards,
Gregory

Answer (score 0):

There are code templates

Goto Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates

Under Code there are different options, maybe yours is Method Body

Click on Edit, remove the comment and Save

Comment: Hello, thanks for your quick reaction. My question was more on how to append automatically after a new field, variable, method a comment. Not removing it...

Comment: Yes I found the template

Comment: I want this added when variable is written. That I do not need to click anywhere to append the template...